# Colour profile stripped from featured image

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

So my photo was chosen for featured image (for which I'm very grateful), however I noticed that it looks darker than I the image I provided, and as I suspected the colour profile has been removed from it. Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 4):

It's probably best to convert it to sRGB. Many browsers don't handle color profiles gracefully.

Comment: It is always best to convert to sRBG when publishing to the web.

Comment: Safari does handle colour profiles though, and had the colour profile been left alone it would have looked fine in that.

Comment: @Ziggamorph: that's not generally useful for everyone, though.

Comment: But there's no reason to strip it! It's not like extra work needs to be done, it just needs to be left alone.

Comment: @Ziggamorph: Isn't this somewhat irrelevant? The point is that the mistake (= not using sRGB) happened already when you submitted the photo. After that, all bets are off. In this case you were lucky that the profile was stripped and therefore you were actually able to notice the mistake. :)

Comment: @MJeffryes As an aside - It's also not this site that strips the colour profile, but the image hosting service (imgurl.com)

Answer (score 0):

The color profile (and all exif data) is probably stripped out as part of the publish in order to **conserve bandwidth**. This is often done when you are dealing with an image that is going to be pushed out to every person who comes to a website, with **3000+ visits a day**, even small differences in the file size can be significant.

As mattdm mentioned, the easy way to deal with this is to use srgb, since your browser will default to that anyway.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it be better if whoever uploads the image converted it to sRGB instead of relying on the submitters to do it?

Comment: @Ziggamorph: If the submissions are not in sRGB, then different people will see different things – and people are voting based on what they see. I think the submitters should go through the trouble of making sure that the submission is in the right format.